# Local Auto-Increment Key

Tags: sql, postgresql, auto-increment

What is the best way to implement an auto-increment key that is "local" to some other column (*i.e.* `comment` id starts from 1 for each blog `post`)?

For instance, on GitHub, the issue number is local to the repository: issue #1 means that it's the first issue of your repo, and makes life easier for everyone by not having to use longer and seemingly random IDs.

For instance given:

```sql
CREATE TABLE post (
    id     bigserial PRIMARY KEY
  , title  varchar(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE "comment" (
    post_id    bigint REFERENCES post NOT NULL
  , id         bigint NOT NULL
  , "comment"  text NOT NULL
  , PRIMARY KEY (id, post_id)
);
```

One way to solve the problem is to calculate the max `id` of all comments for a given `post_id`:

```sql
INSERT INTO post (id, title) VALUES (1, 'first post');

INSERT INTO "comment" (post_id, id, "comment") VALUES (
  1,
  (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(id) + 1, 1) FROM "comment" WHERE post_id = 1 LIMIT 1),
  '1st comment of 1st post'
);
```

^ This feels like a kludge, and I am also worried about possible serialisability issues too.

I wonder what is the best way to implement this (under PostgreSQL)? Thanks!

Comment: I like this question. However, I must say that PKs are not meant to be visible or "sexy". Their purpose is to ensure row uniqueness. Having said that, I still see the need for the sequential numbering. A secondary "visible" column may be useful, though its value may be computed in a deferred way.

Comment: "A secondary "visible" column may be useful, though its value may be computed in a deferred way." Indeed, but how? =)

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the simple method is to forget about it.  That is, create the table like this:

```
create table comments (
    comment_id bigserial primary key,
    post_id bigint REFERENCES post NOT NULL,
    comment text NOT NULL
);
```

And then calculate the value on the fly:

```
create view v_comments as
    select c.*,
           row_number() over (partition by post_id order by comment_id) as post_seqnum
    from comments c;
```

Of course, this is not exactly the same thing.  For instance, the `post_seqnum` does not uniquely identify each row over time -- because a `delete` might change the ordering.

However, this still has a unique identifier for each row that can be used for such purposes.  Plus, there is a *single* primary key column, which is generally preferable for foreign key references and debugging.

Comment: I think this is a really great answer, but as you have mentioned, delete might change the ordering (which is undesirable if we allow objects to be referenced by their IDs [like GitHub issues]).

Comment: @BoraM.Alper . . . You can use soft deletes, if that is an issue.